# Parse a timestamp response file (tsr) using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, cryptography, asn.1

This code is written in python:

```
from asn1crypto import tsp, cms, util
response_file = open('timestamp-response.tsr','rb')
response = tsp.TimeStampResp.load(response_file.read())

token = response['time_stamp_token']
signed_data = token['content']
encap_content_info = signed_data['encap_content_info']
tst_info = encap_content_info['content'].parsed
signer_infos = signed_data['signer_infos']
signer_info = signer_infos[0]
signed_attrs = signer_info['signed_attrs']
signature = signer_info['signature']
```

I can't find way to perform the same action using javascript even the api of the libraries looks the same.

Helpful links:

https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.asn1.tsp.TimeStampResp.html
https://github.com/wbond/asn1crypto/blob/master/asn1crypto/tsp.py

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any ready-to-use library but I believe it should be possible to use [ASN1.js](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/ASN1.js) to parse `TimeStampResp` structure with definitions from [RFC3161](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3161.txt) and extract the data you need.

Parsing DER encoded structure when you have its ASN.1 definition is the same thing as parsing XML structure when you have its XSD definition but it will probably take more time until you get familiar with ASN.1 stuff.

Comment: Thank you, I will do further research considering what you have given.

Comment: Still I can't find a way to parse internal values of timestamp response file (tsr). I have generated the file following this code: freetsa.org/index_en.php

Answer (score 1):

You could try [pkijs](https://pkijs.org/). I did not try it on timestamps (only x509 certificates) but it seems this library does support it. It uses asn1js under the cover.

> Time-stamping request:
>
> - Parsing internal values
> - Getting/setting any internal values
> - Creation of a new Time-stamping request "from scratch"
> - Validation of Time-stamping request signature
>
> Time-stamping response:
>
> - Parsing internal values
> - Getting/setting any internal values
> - Creation of a new Time-stamping response "from scratch"
> - Validation of Time-stamping response signature

Comment: Thank you, I will do further research considering what you have given.

Comment: Still I can't find a way to parse internal values of timestamp response file (tsr). I have generated the file following this code: https://www.freetsa.org/index_en.php